# How does my car's remote keep running?

Tags: electricity, entropy, batteries

Two years ago, I got a new car.  It comes with a wireless remote that provides keyless ignition and can unlock and lock doors at the press of a button.

Just recently, I read somewhere (unfortunately I can't find it now) that even the best batteries we have today will naturally discharge at a rate of approximately 5% per month due to entropy, and that made me wonder.  I have never recharged or changed the battery in this wireless remote, and yet, after well over 20 months, it continues to work.  Why is that?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

The battery in your remote is probably a [lithium manganese oxide battery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_ion_manganese_oxide_battery), and these have a shelf life of 10 to 15 years depending on who you believe. I did try Googling for an authoritative figure but without any luck, though [this article from Varta](http://www.varta-microbattery.com/applications/mb_data/documents/sales_literature_varta/HANDBOOK_Primary_Lithium_Cells_en.pdf) (NB this is a 2MB PDF) cites a ten year shelf life.

Shelf life means when the battery is not connected to anything, and when you aren't pressing the button on the remote the battery inside it isn't connected to anything. So the shelf life applies even though the battery isn't actually on a shelf.

That's why your remote is still working after 20 months, and indeed you can expect it to work for many months to come - subject to how often you use it of course.

Answer (score 0):

It continues to work because the battery does not discharge at 5% per month. It's much less. I have batteries with a use by 2019 date, which I have had for some time.